# Using Excel VBA to run a CMD command

Tags: vba, excel, cmd

I would like to use Excel VBA to run a CMD command.

The basic cmd command is:

```
"C:\Program Files\example program.exe" -w C:\Program files\outputfile.file "dir1" "dir2" "dir n+1"
```

The first part is the location of the program that will merge the files together.
The second part is the file location of the outputted merged files.
And the "dir1".... is the files that will be merged together.

I have code that lists the files to be merged but struggling to get the CMD code to get it so it does what I want as mentioned above. I have tried the following:

```
   Sub RunCMD()

        Dim wsh As Object
        Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
        Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
        Dim locationofprogram as string
       'dir of program that will do the merge
        Dim outputfolder as string
       'dir of where the merged file will go
        Dim listoffiles as string
       'list of files to be merged

        wsh.Run "cmd.exe /S /C locationofprogram & " " & "-w" & " " & outputfolder & " " & listoffiles, windowStyle, waitOnReturn

    End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always create a .bat file, run the file, then delete it.

```
MyFile = "C:\Bat-File\Bat-File.bat"

fnum = FreeFile()
Open MyFile For Output As #fnum
Print #fnum, "C:\Program Files\example program.exe -w C:\Program files\outputfile.file dir1 dir2 dir n+1"    
Close #fnum

Shell MyFile, vbNormalFocus

' wait 10 seconds to let bat file finnish
newHour = Hour(Now()) 
newMinute = Minute(Now()) 
newSecond = Second(Now()) + 10 
waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond) 
Application.Wait waitTime

' delete bat-file
kill MyFile
```

I can't test that example program runs without the " around the dir´s so you have to see what happens.
But if it does not work you need to double enclose the " or use `& CHR(34) &`

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt, send the text to the Immediate Window to see if it still matches the syntax using:

```
 Debug.Print "cmd.exe /S /C " & locationofprogram & " " & "-w" & " " & outputfolder & " " & listoffiles
```

If that works, use:

```
 wsh.Run "cmd.exe /S /C " & locationofprogram & " " & "-w" & " " & outputfolder & " " & listoffiles, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

Comment: Thanks CLR for the help. I found that whenever I ran that code, it wouldn't do anything. If I put "ipconfig", it would work but with my long string, it wouldn't parse into the cmd command line. But thanks for the help!

Comment: It should work. The only thing you have to watch out for is spaces in the filename or folder names. If there are spaces, you have to wrap paths in double-quotes. Never mind though, it looks like you found a workaround but FYI there is nothing wrong with using the shell in the way you originally described if you get the syntax right.

Comment: hhhmm I guess I should have spend a bit more time with the code above as its simpler than what I used in the end. Hopefully anyone who stumbles on this thread will find it useful tho! Cheers CLR!